# Count Unique Rows filtered by blank cell in Excel

Tags: excel, count

I am trying to count unique rows with blank values in another column.
I tried using the following formula and it did not return the correct values:

```
=SUBTOTAL(103, $A$2:$A$17) - SUBTOTAL(103, $B$2:$B$17)
```

Here is the table structure.
[image]

Comment: Can you share the logic or end goal for this - aside from simply counting unique rows with blanks?

Comment: The goal is to find all unique names having date as null/blank. I have omitted other columns for simplicity(whose values would be needing later).

Comment: If you say unique, you have only 4 unique values for where date is null/blank, how it is 5?

Comment: Sorry for the typo.. it should be 4 in this case.. I misplaced some values while creating the dummy data..

Answer (score 1):

I think this may work for you. Use flowing formula-

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF($B$2:$B$19="",IF($A$2:$A$19<>"",MATCH("~"&$A$2:$A$19,$A$2:$A$19&"",0))),ROW($A$2:$A$19)-ROW($A$2)+1),1))
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula as it is an array formula.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can enter this as a array formula.

```
{=SUM((--(FREQUENCY(IF(B2:B17<>"","",MATCH(A2:A17,A2:A17,0)),ROW(A2:A17)-ROW(A2)+1)>0)))}
```